# What does the below error mean in PySpark and how to resolve it?

Tags: apache-spark

I am using this tutorial: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html

I have tried the following lines:

```
textFile=sc.textFile("README.md")
textFile.count()
```

Below is the output that I receive instead of the desired result, 126.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ashish/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1004, in count
    return self.mapPartitions(lambda i: [sum(1 for _ in i)]).sum()
  File "/home/ashish/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 995, in sum
    return self.mapPartitions(lambda x: [sum(x)]).fold(0, operator.add)
  File "/home/ashish/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 869, in fold
    vals = self.mapPartitions(func).collect()
  File "/home/ashish/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 771, in collect
    port = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
  File "/home/ashish/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 813, in __call__
  File "/home/ashish/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 45, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  *******File "/home/ashish/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 308, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: java.net.ConnectException: Call From gangwar/127.0.1.1 to localhost:54310 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused*******
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:791)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:731)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1472)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy20.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:752)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:1988)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1118)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.getFileStatus(Globber.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.glob(Globber.java:252)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globStatus(FileSystem.java:1644)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:257)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:228)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:199)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.getPartitions(PythonRDD.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1929)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:405)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:530)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:494)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:607)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2800(Client.java:368)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1438)
    ... 56 more
+h
```

Answer (score 0):

You should actually read the error yourself:

```
: java.net.ConnectException: Call From gangwar/127.0.1.1 to localhost:54310 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused*******
```

http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused

Comment: I know the error (Connection refused error) but donot know how to resolve it. I am new to both ubuntu as well as spark. I googled it but did not found any solution. It will be a great help if anyone can provide the solution for the same.

Comment: It is literally impossible for somebody to tell you what the issue is with any certainty. Only you have access to your network, so only you can debug what is not right. It could be one of a hundred issues, its an equivalent error to "I can't connect to the internet". As explained here: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/YourNetworkYourProblem

What were the outcomes of the 9 steps on the page I linked in the original answer?